# On the definition of uniform convergence in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space, and, for each $y\in Y$, let $\{X_n^y\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence of random variables converging uniformly (in $y$) in probability to a random variable $X^y$. That is, $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb P\left(\sup_{y\in Y} \left\vert X_n^y - X^y \right\vert > \varepsilon\right) = 0 \quad\forall\varepsilon>0. \tag{1}\label{1}  $$

This appears to be the standard definition of uniform convergence in probability. However, it seems to me that there is an alternative "reasonable" definition(*) of uniform convergence in probability, which is $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{y\in Y}\mathbb P\left( \left\vert X_n^y - X^y \right\vert > \varepsilon\right) = 0 \quad\forall\varepsilon>0. \tag{2}\label{2}  $$

It is easy to see that \eqref{1} implies \eqref{2}.

This leads me to the following questions.

1. Why is \eqref{1} taken to be the standard definition of uniform convergence in probability?
2. Is \eqref{2} in fact weaker than \eqref{1}? That is, is there a sequence of random variables that converge according to \eqref{2} but to not according to \eqref{1}?
3. Are there natural conditions where \eqref{2} is equivalent to \eqref{1}? By "natural conditions" I mean conditions we typically expect sequences to satisfy, though I'm open to alternative interpretations of "natural".

I imagine the answer to my first question has to do with the fact that \eqref{1} conforms more closely to our usual definition of uniform convergence on, say, a metric space, while \eqref{2} doesn't, but I haven't managed to formalise this properly. On the other hand, for \eqref{1}, I believe we need to take extra care to guarantee the measurability of $\sup_y \vert X_n^y - X^y \vert$, but no such issue is faced by \eqref{2}.

For my third question, I am happy to see answers that specialise to contexts where uniform convergence in probability is used often. One example of such a context is in stochastic processes, where $Y\subseteq [0,\infty]$, and each $X_n^y$ might be (a.s.) càdlàg in $y$.

(*) By this I mean that if you told me to write down the definition of uniform convergence in probability, and I didn't already know the standard definition, I would be unsure about whether you meant \eqref{1} or \eqref{2}.

Comment: 2) rarely implies 1). Compactness  and smoothness in $y$ does not give this implication. This is because the supremum in 1) can be attained at points varying with $\omega$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks, will take that part out.